# automatically fix indentation in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I have multiple documents that have space-based indentation depths (2,3,4 spaces) I had a look and couldn't seem to find anything that would allow me to automatically set the indentations to be the same. I could write a regex or something similar to fix it but I'd like to avoid that.

Auto indent settings didn't seem to do the trick, I guess potentially because the indentation is legal just ugly. Also its not mixed tabs and spaces which there is a fn for.

Comment: what is wrong with the regex? You can write a simple extension that will fix the file in the way you want

Comment: So you just want to take all groups of 2/3/4 spaces at the beginning of lines and normalize them to which choice of indentation?